# Is there something wrong with my linux code to check memory usage?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-leaks

I have a question about code below.
Is curMemoryInfo.phyMem the current process's RAM memory usage?

I'm having a Memory Leak and it's only happening on Linux.
I am checking the memory leak with the code below on Linux and
using the Visual Studio debugger on Windows.

Is there something wrong with my code to check for memory leaks in Linux?

```cpp
FILE* file;
char processStatPath[128] = { 0, };

sprintf( processStatPath, "/proc/%d/statm", inputPId );

file = fopen( processStatPath, "r" );

if( !file )
{
    //NV_TRACE_MSG(TRUE, "PID:%d Not available!!!", inputPId) ;
    return false;
}

unsigned long size = -1; // VmSize
unsigned long resident = -1; // VmRSS
unsigned long share = -1; // shared
unsigned long text = -1; // text size
unsigned long lib = -1; // lib size
unsigned long data = -1; // VmData + VmStk
unsigned long dt = -1; // dirty page

int ret = fscanf( file, "%lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu %lu",
                  &size,
                  &resident,
                  &share,
                  &text,
                  &lib,
                  &data,
                  &dt );

fclose( file );

curMemoryInfo.phyMem = ( resident - share )*pageSize; // non swap memory (physical memory)
curMemoryInfo.wholeMem = ( size - share )*pageSize; // whole memory (swap + physical memory)
curMemoryInfo.sharedMem = share * pageSize;// shared memory
...
...
// compare wiht prev_memory_usage
...
...
```

Comment: Please learn how to use tools such as [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) which will help you locate leaks much more easily (with a debug build it can tell you exactly when and where in your code the memory was allocated).

Comment: I have a already free memory in my code. but only increasing not window but linux.......

Comment: Linux tend not to release pages for a process when the memory is free'd. That could lead to false positives. I really recommend you use proper tools to detect if there really are memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will take your advice :)